# Link button inside a Repeater control, how to change the background/foreground color of clicked item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

I would like to show list of days in week (dynamic, some time all days, sometime only 2-3)
and then user will click on day and refresh the same page.
Above functionality is achieved by below code.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="DayList" Runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDayList" Runat="server" CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "wkdayVal")%>'
    OnCommand="lbDayList_click" 
    DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "wkday")%>
    </asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>                                                                            
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want to show the clicked day in different color!! Please help in achieving this functionality!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a **styles.css** page and using the `CssClass=""` attribute of your LinkButton?

In your styles.css file you would have something like the following:

```
.Visited
{
    color: #fff;
    background: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Then your link button's css attribute would use something like

```
CssClass="visited"
```

You'll want to do this on the PreRender portion of your Repeater so set the Repeater's `OnPreRender` attribute to `Repeater_OnPreRender`. Then in your codebehind create a function like so

```
protected void Repeater_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//get the index of the selected item

//loop through your items colleciton until you find the item with the corresponding index

//find your link button

//set your link button's css attribute.

}
```

The reason  you would perform this in the `PreRender` stage is because your repeater already has the data loaded into it and the HTML that is passed back to the web browser has not yet been created.

Hope this helps. GS

Comment: Better to make a class (e.g. "MyLink") and then style MyLink.visited, etc. Then, just set CssClass="MyLink". Let HTML and CSS do the work, not C# code :)